# unable to divide mat-table header

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

might be a very simple question but am unable to figure out..not sure if this a CSS change or something else.
I need a divider between my table header similar as below screenshot(highlighted).
[image]

This is what I have got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have these only headers and you want the border before **Grade**

```
mat-header-cell:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid 
}
```

Here is an Running [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5maf8n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Thanks. it worked but but it gave me partial results Please have a look at the updated question above(have added a screenshot of its current working). It adds the border only on the cell where as I want to add to the entire header....can you please suggest something else?

Comment: add some padding I think it will give the result

Answer (score 1):

You need to add left border to each cell except the first one - and since the alignment will be off, you can add some padding to make it look pretty

relevant **CSS**:

```
th.mat-header-cell { border-left: 2px solid red; }
th.mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) { border-left: none;}
th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell { padding:5px; }
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked but but it gave me partial results Please have a look at the updated question above(have added a screenshot of its current working). It adds the border only on the cell where as I want to add to the entire header....can you please suggest something else?

Comment: @Dwayne, can you recreate your issue in the following stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thgq75?file=src/app/table-basic-example.css